# How can i get cookie from PyQt QWebView?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qwebview

I am using PyQt to load a website, once it's loaded i want to get the cookies from it. Is this possible with PyQt, or should i use some other module for that?

```
    web = QtWebKit.QWebView()
    web.load(web.QUrl("http://google.com"))
    // get the cookie from website
    web.show()
```

EDIT:
Basically, I want to know is how i can:
 1. Load a website from webview
 2. Once the page is loaded, print all the cookies that are set.

Comment: I've never used it but I found a function `QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager.setCookieJar(cookieJar)` and also a class named `QtNetwork.QNetworkCookieJar`.  The docs look pretty sketchy.  BTW cookies live on the client side, not the server side, so when you say you want to "get the cookies from it [the site]" I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I mean i want to get it from the client. `web.load(web.QUrl("http://google.com"))` allows me to load a website from the python application. I want to get the cookies that are set when the site is loaded. 
I know about that function, but i don't know how to integrate it with `QWebView`